# Access JavaScript variable from HTML element attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to access a JavaScript variable from an attribute from an HTML element?

For example:

```
<a href="#" id="id1" my-attr="test">click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var test="hello world!";
$("#id1").click(function() { alert($(this).attr('my-attr')) });
</script>
```

What I want to happen is the alert to show "hello world!" but obviously instead it shows "test"

I know I can accomplish this if I use eval(), I was just wondering if there was another way.  Some type of JavaScript reflection or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="id1" my-attr="test">click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var test="hello world!";
$("#id1").click(function() { 
          $(this).attr('my-attr',test);
          alert($(this).attr('my-attr')); 
});
</script>
```

you need to put your variable test in that `.attr` function. and don't use `my-attr` as custom property, instead use `Data-attr`, so that you can access it using the `.data` function in jquery.